# Elastic search API Query a field where a value 'is one of'

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to make a query to extract information on restriction similar to '**is one of**' as a filter in Kibana. 
I successfully extract if it's a strict single value but if multiple - not.

**Single value:**

```
response = await client.search({
            index: index,
            body: {
                query: {
                    match: {"organization_classification_id": 2}
                },
                _source: {}
            }
        });
```

**Multiple value:** But I also need to have several **ids**:

```
response = await client.search({
                index: index,
                body: {
                    query: {
                        match: {"organization_classification_id": [2, 4,7]}
                    },
                    _source: {}
                }
            });
```

I tried matchAll, multi_match but it doesn't work
I have an error:

```
Error: [parsing_exception] [multi_match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [organization_classification_id], with { line=1 & col=59 }
```

Comment: If you are matching exact values, you could look into trying a `terms` match: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: Thanks, Cory, works as needed.

Comment: You should post your completed and working code as an answer chunk for posterity.